# What do these numbers on the top of these mini linear actuators denote?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I'm building 42082 and there are 4 of these but 3 unique numbers in the tops.

- 20X8 on two
- 29X8 on one
- 35X8 on another

I'm guessing they are serial numbers from machines that made them but I wondered if someone had a better idea.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First two digits represent week of production followed by a year.

20X8 - 20th week of 2018.

These codes used for quality control. LEGO Customer Service may ask you to provide this number if there were an issue with a set or particular part.

Similar code exist on box seals too.

Comment: Why “X8” instead of “18”? What do other years/decades use?

Comment: This is something unknown, probably has some company internal meaning. For example you can find "S" on boxes, "K" on some other parts. I have an old motor base from set of year 2009. It has "J8" for 2008 production year.

Comment: If they're using multiple letter codes/year they presumably refer to different production lines, or production runs.